# Cyclomatic Complexity for Salesforce Configuration work

Tags: apex

Any idea how to calculate the [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) for Configuration work in Salesforce?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you need draw control flow graph of your code.

Complexity M = E − N + 2P,
where
E = the number of edges of the graph.
N = the number of nodes of the graph.
P = the number of connected components.

for details : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity